# How to Alow Two Letters at the end of string with regex?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have the following pattern:

```
^(01|04|05|06|PP|PPC)[0-9]*$
```

This works if the string starts with `PP` and ends with numbers.

How to allow `UK` at the end? I want to match a string like: `PPC12345678UK`

Comment: should UK be on the end always or is it optional?

Comment: yes It is Optional

Comment: ^(01|04|05|06|PP|PPC)[0-9]*(UK)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(01|04|05|06|PP|PPC)[0-9]*(UK)?$
```

In regular expressions, [`?` means "0 or 1"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), i.e. it's equivalent to writing `{0,1}`. It makes the attribute "optional".

So, the above regex will match strings like:

> PP23462937
>
> PPC328472936UK

And it will **not** match strings like:

> 01937492384U
>
> 068203472K

Comment: Only the first pattern has been marked as group, maybe R01 doesn't want to capture anything else than this first group. using (?:...) non capturing groups may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use an optional *non*-capturing group for optional *sequences* of atoms in a regex. Besides, when an alternation group is used, it is best to make sure each branch (`|`-separated) does not match at the same location.

So, I'd recommend:

```
^(?:0[1456]|PPC?)[0-9]*(?:UK)?$
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:0[1456]|PPC?)` - either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `0[1456]` - `0` followed with `1`, `4`, `5` or `6`
  - `|` - or
  - `PPC?` - `PP` or `PPC`.
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `(?:UK)?` - an optiona `UK` substring
- `$` - end of string.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a0%5b1456%5d%7cPPC%3f%29%5b0-9%5d*%28%3f%3aUK%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=PPC12345678UK%0d%0aPPC12345678%0d%0aPP12345678UK&o=m):
[image]

And here is the regex diagram:[image]

Answer (score 0):

just add UK at the end
`^(01|04|05|06|PP|PPC)[0-9]*UK$`

Or, as @Tom Lord just responded, with question mark if optional.: 
`^(01|04|05|06|PP|PPC)[0-9]*(UK)?$`

If you don't want to capture the UK at the end use (?:) non capturing groups: `^(01|04|05|06|PP|PPC)[0-9]*(?:UK)?$`

Comment: This also allows **only** `K` or **only** `U` at the end, which is not what was required.

Comment: this allows separate U or K at the end